# How do I fix Apache after upgrading Raspbian to Stretch?

Tags: raspbian, update

I just upgraded my Raspbian Pi from Wheezy to Stretch, and all of my Apache web pages are broken.

For example, my Nextcloud webpage literally looks like this:

[image]

(This is the text:)

```
* @author Lukas Reschke * @author Morris Jobke * @author Robin Appelman * @author Thomas MÃ¼ller * @author Vincent Petry * * @license AGPL-3.0 * * This code is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify * it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License, version 3, * as published by the Free Software Foundation. * * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the * GNU Affero General Public License for more details. * * You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License, version 3, * along with this program. If not, see * */ // Show warning if a PHP version below 5.6.0 is used, this has to happen here // because base.php will already use 5.6 syntax. if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0') === -1) { echo 'This version of Nextcloud requires at least PHP 5.6.0
'; echo 'You are currently running ' . PHP_VERSION . '. Please update your PHP version.'; return; } try { require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/base.php'; OC::handleRequest(); } catch(\OC\ServiceUnavailableException $ex) { \OC::$server->getLogger()->logException($ex, array('app' => 'index')); //show the user a detailed error page OC_Response::setStatus(OC_Response::STATUS_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE); OC_Template::printExceptionErrorPage($ex); } catch (\OC\HintException $ex) { OC_Response::setStatus(OC_Response::STATUS_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE); OC_Template::printErrorPage($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getHint()); } catch (\OC\User\LoginException $ex) { OC_Response::setStatus(OC_Response::STATUS_FORBIDDEN); OC_Template::printErrorPage($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getMessage()); } catch (Exception $ex) { \OC::$server->getLogger()->logException($ex, array('app' => 'index')); //show the user a detailed error page OC_Response::setStatus(OC_Response::STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); OC_Template::printExceptionErrorPage($ex); } catch (Error $ex) { \OC::$server->getLogger()->logException($ex, array('app' => 'index')); OC_Response::setStatus(OC_Response::STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); OC_Template::printExceptionErrorPage($ex); }
```

The Tiny Tiny RSS page shows the following error

```
Fatal Error: You forgot to copy config.php-dist to config.php and edit it.\n"; exit; } // we need a separate check here because functions.php might get parsed // incorrectly before 5.3 because of :: syntax. if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) { print "Fatal Error: PHP version 5.3.0 or newer required.\n"; exit; } set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) ."/include" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()); require_once "autoload.php"; require_once "sessions.php"; require_once "functions.php"; require_once "sanity_check.php"; require_once "version.php"; require_once "config.php"; require_once "db-prefs.php"; require_once "lib/Mobile_Detect.php"; $mobile = new Mobile_Detect(); if (!init_plugins()) return; if (!$_REQUEST['mobile']) { if ($mobile->isTablet() && PluginHost::getInstance()->get_plugin("digest")) { header('Location: backend.php?op=digest'); exit; } else if ($mobile->isMobile() && PluginHost::getInstance()->get_plugin("mobile")) { header('Location: backend.php?op=mobile'); exit; } else if ($mobile->isMobile() && PluginHost::getInstance()->get_plugin("digest")) { header('Location: backend.php?op=digest'); exit; } } login_sequence(); header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
get_hooks(PluginHost::HOOK_TOOLBAR_BUTTON) as $p) { echo $p->hook_toolbar_button(); } ?>
```

And Nagios says `You don't have permission to access /nagios3/< on this server.` and a bunch of visual artefacts.

I searched the web, and some of this may be fixed by installing php, but I think this is already installed.

```
 $ dpkg -l php
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                 Version         Architecture    Description
+++-====================-===============-===============-=============================================
ii  php                  1:7.0+49        all             server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language
```

How can I fix my Apache pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was related to the upgrade of php from version 5 to 7.0. I looked at `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`. This previously contained the php5 module, which was now absent and not even available. I fixed the errors with:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```